# How to run a bash command from a second terminal without closing the first one

Tags: bash, automation, mariadb, cloud-foundry, ssh-tunnel

I have the following problem.
In Cloud foundry, if you want to access to a service instance you have first to create an SSH Tunnel to a host app, then from a second shell access the service.
So in my case, I want to access a MariaDB Database hosted on Cloud Foundry.

So I first open the SSH Tunnel

```
cf ssh -L 63306:<IP ADDRESS OF THE DB>:3306 YOUR-HOST-APP
```

then, keeping the first shell open, in a second shell access the DB with the following command:

```
mysql -u <username> -h 0 -p -D <DB> -P 63306
```

Now, I want that these two commands are executed in an automation script.
How can I execute the second command in a second shell, keeping the first shell open in a script?
Could be both Python or bash script.

Comment: can the `cf` call be placed in the background and then after a brief wait (for the `cf` to connect, eg, 1 sec? 2 secs?) make the `mysql` call?

Comment: If just sending `cf` to the background doesn't work try `coproc: coproc [NAME] command [redirections]`

Comment: put the ssh in background with `ssh -f`?

Comment: You can also use `ssh` directly, https://github.com/cloudfoundry/diego-ssh#cloud-foundry-via-cloud-controller-and-uaa. So if `cf ssh` doesn't let you background the process, then you can use `ssh` directly and do that.